# Get top 50 websites visited by traffic

Tags: isa-server

I'm logging both web proxy and firewall traffic under the logging tab.

How would I get a top 50 list of websites that use the most traffic.
I need the website addresses, not just the IP address as an IP address would be hosting several different sites.

Comment: You must specify what kind of proxy and firewall you are using.

Comment: ISA 2006 proxy and firewall, just using this logging -> http://cl.ly/2h2c0b3T2V0N0C3j3o2s

Comment: That's not a useful screenshot. For anyone not following the link, it's a picture of two links saying "Firewall log settings" and "Web Proxy log settings"

Comment: That was just to show the logging method I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're logging in W3C format in a text file then you can run [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) or similar over it.

From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb794817.aspx):

> Text File Logging
>
> You can save ISA Server logs to a text file, in one of the following
>   formats:
>
> World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) format. W3C logs contain both data and directives, describing the version, date, and logged fields.
>   Because the fields are described in the file, unselected fields are
>   not logged. The tab character is used as a delimiter. Date and time
>   are in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
>
> ISA Server format. ISA Server format contains only data with no directives. All fields are always logged. Unselected fields are logged
>   with a dash, to indicate that they are empty. The comma character is
>   used as a delimiter. The date and time fields are in local time as
>   configured on the computer.
>
> By default, log files are saved in the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft ISA
>   Server\ISALogs folder.

Comment: Or LogParser 2.2 from Microsoft.com